# Unity 5 Animator controls - What are their Unity 4 correspondent?

Tags: unity

I am following a tutorial that is made with Unity 5, but claims to be compatible with Unity 4.6

I am working with the Animator panel, and I was wondering where could I find certain controls on the Unity 4 version. I highlighted them in a red square.

[image]

Basically stuff that has to do with duration of transitions and checking the transition as not having an exit time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exit Time is a condition parameter in Unity 4 -> you'll have to add it / assign it to the specific transition you're working on.

The transition duration you can tweak using the timeline just below this in your image. The offset and interrupt are new features AFAIK.

Hope this helps.